# Monitor ppp0 traffic usage with Linux

Tags: traffic, bandwidth-measuring

Hey I'm developing a 3G connected device with a raspberry Pi. My mobile provider allows me to use 50 MB/month.

This device will be installed somewhere nobody can have physically access to.
My concern is to avoid data traffic overuse. I need a tool to measure all the accumulated traffic going through (in and out) the ppp0 interface in order to disconnect the interface until next month if the 50MB limit is reached.

I tried with `ifconfig` but since I have some disconnections the counter is always reset at each reconnection.

I tried `ntop` and `iftop` but from what I understood these are tools for measuring real-time traffic.

I'm really looking for some kind of cumulative traffic use, like we usually can find on smartphones.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try vnstat with vnstati

Its quiet easy to install, most Linuxdistros have it in their repos and it generates beautyful images:
[SCREENIE](http://humdi.net/vnstat/coloredit/vnstati.php?bg=FFFFFF&edge=AEAEAE&header=606060&headertitle=FFFFFF&headerdate=FFFFFF&text=000000&line=B0B0B0&rx=92CF00&tx=606060&linel=-&rxd=-&txd=-)